# Is there a quasi-standard set of attributes to annotate thread safety, immutability etc.?

Tags: c#

Except for a blog post here and there, describing the custom attributes someone created, but that do not seem to get any traction - like one describing how to [enforce immutability](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kevinpilchbisson/enforcing-immutability-in-code), another one on [Documenting Thread Safety](https://larryparkerdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/documenting-thread-safety/), modeling the attributes after [JCIP annotations](https://jcip.net/) - is there any standard emerging? Anything MS might be planning for the future?

This is something that should be standard, if there's to be any chance of interoperability between libraries concurrency-wise. Both for documentation purposes, and also to feed static / dynamic test tools.

If MS isn't doing anything in that direction, it could be done on CodePlex - but I couldn't find anything there, either.

<opinion>Concurrency and thread safety are really hard in imperative and object-languages like C# and Java, we should try to tame it, until we hopefully switch to more appropriate languages.</opinion>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with both immutability and thread safety are that they are not black and white concepts, but there are a number of possible guarantees in that regard. Reducing that to simple attributes might be hard. IMO a simple `ThreadSafe` and `Immutable` attribute isn't enough. Still working out a set of attributes capturing at least the most important semantics sounds promising to me.

For example take an `AddRange` method. It might be thread safe enough to never corrupt the state of the underlying collection, but might not be atomic. A common implementation with these properties might be just calling an atomic `Add` method for each element.

On the immutability side we have different aspects too:

- Offering only readonly accessors or truly never changing
- Depth of immutability i.e. are sub-objects immutable too
- Physical vs. logical immutability. For example lazy initialization does not change the visible state, but changes the internal state.

One annotation is this context already exists: `Pure` for side effect free methods.

Comment: I agree that it is not simple. But I think it should be done. It's too hard to do complex software without it, especially integrating multiple libraries. Thanks for pointing out Pure ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx), that's a start and I'll therefore accept your answer, as it seems to be the best we can get right now, in terms of an 'quasi-standard' of at least SOMEthing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a set of standards (even quasi) right now. Isolated projects do some of this in their own way. I[n a thread post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/d1c13af4-a637-44e7-a0b4-27c05c7049c8) they talk about immutability via code contracts and even baking directly into the type system. I've seen even less about thread safety.

Comment: If every project implements their own system, it's hard to integrate different libraries and build or use static / dynamic analysis tools to verify things.

Answer (score 0):

For example, there are different kinds of “threadsafe”: 1. Can be used on a background thread. 2. Can be used on different threads for different instances. 3. Can be used on different threads for one instance. And there is the situation where threadsafe doesn’t mean useful: If on thread adds an object with key “abc” to a dictionary and another thread removes an object with that key, the operations might be threadsafe but the outcome depends on which one runs first.

Same with immutable: is an object caching results immutable, if the behaviour is unchanged, except for timing? If an object contains a reference to a mutable string and I change the string? The object hasn’t changed, it contains the same string reference??

Comment: Is this an answer, a question or a comment?